# My laptop wallpaper change when laptop locked more than 30 minutes

Tags: 19.10

My ubuntu version is 19.10. Asus laptop.  Wallpaper changing not helping. This will reset after reboot.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/gs-change-wallpaper.html.en In _Background_ settings, one of those images displayed has a little clock icon in the lower right corner, which indicates that the background image will change after a set time. Try selecting another, if you have that one selected.

Comment: Its not changing time to time. It only happens when screen lock status.

Comment: https://ibb.co/LSKW5n4 this image might help